# Switching User-Agent in Firefox 4

Tags: http, firefox, firebug, user-agent

How can I fake/switch the User-Agent in Firefox 4?  The [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) Add-On doesnt seem to work with Firefox 4.  I have firebug, but I'm unaware of any feature for switching user-agent in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User agent switcher version 0.7.3 claims to support Firefox 4, and I've been using it with FF4 for a while. I just tested it on whatsmyuseragent.com and it seemd to work fine.

Comment: got it-- just realized that i had to switch the menu back on.. firefox 4 will take some getting used to

Answer (score 1):

In the address bar type:

```
about:config
```

In the filter type:

```
general.useragent.override
```

Comment: Nothing with that value listed right now.. should I right click and press "New"?

Comment: by the way thanks for making me aware of the fact I have had my work machine's FF useragent set to "googlebot" for a VERY long time.  Not a good idea, since some weaker javascript code uses useragent to change it's behavior.  A better approach is to feature detect...

Comment: yes..they changed this not so long ago, I think the original version had it there..

Comment: btw, I LOVE this site: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: Cool, your method worked.. Only thing that'd make it even better is if I could somehow just click a button to turn the override on and off rather than going to config every time

Comment: cool, can you accept my answer ;) BTW, I use that same plugin, so hopefully they just update it for the new version..

Comment: hey, i found you can actually get the new plugin working, you just have to enable the menu toolbar.  im giving you an upvote, but im going to accept the other answer cus it turns out i was wrong about being unable to use the plugin