# How can I (really) change my browser identification (user agent AND javascript attributes)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, spoofing

A website can get information about your browser and system via several methods:

- user agent,
- javascript attributes (like `navigator.platform`),
- profiling by testing avalaible browser features (Javascript API for example),
- asking available browser plugins,
- etc.

This website shows some of these: http://www.webreference.com/tools/browser/javascript.html

**At least, I would like to know how to spoof the user agent *and* javascript attributes so that the website cannot detect my OS.** I did it once by patching Chromium source code, but I'm looking for an easier way.

I'm interested in solutions for Chromium (Chrome) and/or Firefox.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/283670/switching-user-agent-in-firefox-4?rq=1

Comment: @techie007 **I already saw all these questions, none consider the javascript attributes.** You can check that on the website I mention in my question, it will still detect Linux or Windows even if you change your user agent because that information is available through Javascript `navigator.platform`. Hence the "really" in my question title. This is not a simple duplicate.

Comment: **Maybe you should have noted you already saw/considered those in your question**.  Can you explain how your question is actually different than what's mentioned in [How can I make my browser lie about my operating system?](http://superuser.com/questions/681143/how-can-i-make-my-browser-lie-about-my-operating-system)?  To me, they both appear to be about trying to spoof the OS detected by JavaScript.